# Compound Interest on cash payment

Tags: finance

A man buys a scooter on making a cash down payment of 16,224 and promises to pay two more yearly equal instalments of equivalent amount in next two years. If the rate of Interest is 4% p.a compounded yearly, then, the caash value of the scooter is::
(i) 40,000
(ii) 46,824
(iii) 46,000
(iv) 50,000

So, If i assume theat the net cash value of the scooter is X.
The, the amount left after making a cash payment of 16,224 should be ( X - 16,224 ).

Now, this man has to pay 2 yearly equal instalments.
So, Let each instalment be Y.

So, I can caluculate the present worth of this instalment Y in two successive years and Get the value Y as;;

( P.w of Y in 1st year ) + ( P.W of Y in 2nd year ) = X - 16,224.

But, the number of variables here are excessive.

How, do I solve this..?? Help.

Comment: Am I doing it in a wrong way ?????

Comment: How should I think about such questions ??